# Why is ArrayList's sort method faster than Arrays' in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

The goal of the following code is to sort 300,000 int numbers. I find that the duration of ArrayList's sort() is less than Arrays' sort(). Internally, they use the same algorithm to sort. ArrayList uses Arrays' sort() to sort its element data.

```
public class EasySort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Read data from file, number split by ","
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("testdata2.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader  bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line=null;
        try {
            line=bufferedReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // use split method to generate a String array to save numbers
        String[] strArray=line.split(",");

        //Convert string array to ArrayList<Integer>
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String str:strArray){
            integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }

        //Sort by ArrayList
        long t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
        integerList.sort(((p1,p2)->(p1.intValue()<p2.intValue()?-1:p1.intValue()>p2.intValue()?1:0)));
        long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("ArrayList Sort duration:"+(t1-t0));

        //Convert string array to Integer array
        Integer[] integerArray=new Integer[strArray.length];
        int i=0;
        for(String str:strArray){
            integerArray[i++]=Integer.parseInt(str);
        }

        //Sort by Arrays
        t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(integerArray, ((p1,p2)->(p1.intValue()<p2.intValue()?-1:p1.intValue()>p2.intValue()?1:0)));
        t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Arrays duration:"+(t1-t0));
    }
}
```

The result is as follows:
ArrayList Sort duration:211
Arrays duration:435

I checked the source code of ArrayList. It use Arrays.sort() in its own sort method.

```
 @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
        final int expectedModCount = modCount;
        Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
        if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
        modCount++;
    }
```

So, in my opinion, my code should show the same duration. But I tried many times, and the results are similar. What happened?

Java version: 8
Operating System: Windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collections vs Arrays regarding sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208133/collections-vs-arrays-regarding-sort)

Comment: which Java version you using?

Comment: `List<Integer>` can be sorted without a comparator (`Integer` already implements `Comparable`); so, `integerList.sort(null)` will do. And, is it required to create `Integer [] integerArray`? Use an array of primitive `int`'s; and use `Arrays.sort(intArray)`.  You may see different results.

Comment: How many times had you tried? I have tested on my machine with ```ArrayList<Integer>``` and ```Integer[]```, they are almost the same time.

Comment: [How do I write a correct microbenchmark in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/3788176)

Comment: @prasad, I simplified my problem from a bigger project. So you can consider that I have a kind of object, and the object contains int field which can be sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a warm-up issue - but exactly why I don't know.

Using this code:

```
public void test() {
    Integer[] a = randomData(10000000);

    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i : a) {
        integerList.add(i);
    }

    long t0, t1;
    //Sort by ArrayList
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    integerList.sort(((p1, p2) -> (p1.intValue() < p2.intValue() ? -1 : p1.intValue() > p2.intValue() ? 1 : 0)));
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("ArrayList duration:" + (t1 - t0));


    //Sort by Arrays
    Integer[] integerArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Arrays.sort(integerArray, ((p1, p2) -> (p1.intValue() < p2.intValue() ? -1 : p1.intValue() > p2.intValue() ? 1 : 0)));
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Arrays duration:" + (t1 - t0));

}

Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

private Integer[] randomData(int n) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    return a;
}
```

and moving the two sorts into different orders I get:

> Arrays duration:4209
>
> ArrayList duration:4570
>
> ArrayList duration:6776
>
> Arrays duration:4684

So if `ArrayList` is sorted first it takes longer.

So @AndyTurner's comment is correct - refer to [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

*Java 8 - Windows 10*

Comment: if it's warmup, why arraylist numbers are worse even if it goes after array? also interesting behaviour - if you decrease array size, arraylist sorting will be faster in any position

Comment: JIT and other Java optimization techniques make it very hard  to correctly setup micro-benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

They should be the same, I dont know why you had different results. Below is my code and I have almost the same time. For `T[]` and `ArrayList<T>` both will invoke `Arrays.sort(T[], ...)` which will then use merge sort or tim sort.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Integer[] array = new Integer[300000];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(array.length);  
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));    

long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
Arrays.sort(array, 0 ,array.length);
long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
list.sort(null);
long c = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(b - a);
System.out.println(c - b);
```

Comment: I have run your code , b-a=446, c-d=91. My Java version is 8. Which is yours?

Comment: @David.Ren I got both 220~240, My java version is 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I tried using Java 8. Note that there is an array is of `int`s, an array of `Integer`s and the `List` is of `Integer`s. In addition the `Integer` array is sorted using the `Arrays.parallelSort()`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class TestingSorts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t0 = 0L;
        long t1 = 0L;
        // Run this procedure 10 times
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            // Create an int array and Integer List filled with random numbers
            int [] intArray = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt())
                        .limit(300_000)
                        .toArray();
            Integer [] integerArray = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt())
                        .limit(300_000)
                        .boxed()
                        .toArray(n -> new Integer[n]);
            Integer [] integerArrayP = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt())
                        .limit(300_000)
                        .boxed()
                        .toArray(n -> new Integer[n]);
            List<Integer> intList = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt())
                        .limit(300_000)
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
            // Sort the List and the arrays
            t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            intList.sort(null);
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(i + ") ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: " + (t1 - t0));
            t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(integerArray, Comparator.naturalOrder());
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(i + ") Integer[ ] sort duration: " + (t1 - t0));
            t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.parallelSort(integerArrayP, Comparator.naturalOrder());
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(i + ") Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: " + (t1 - t0));
            t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(intArray);
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(i + ") int[ ] sort duration: " + (t1 - t0));
        }
    }
}
```

**Results** (on a Windows 7 64 bit OS running on CORE i3 processor):

```
1) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 200
1) Integer[ ] sort duration: 424
1) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 414
1) int[ ] sort duration: 136
2) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 143
2) Integer[ ] sort duration: 101
2) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 56
2) int[ ] sort duration: 33
3) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 124
3) Integer[ ] sort duration: 118
3) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 96
3) int[ ] sort duration: 42
4) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 108
4) Integer[ ] sort duration: 102
4) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 92
4) int[ ] sort duration: 57
5) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 142
5) Integer[ ] sort duration: 113
5) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 118
5) int[ ] sort duration: 31
6) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 113
6) Integer[ ] sort duration: 103
6) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 58
6) int[ ] sort duration: 32
7) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 115
7) Integer[ ] sort duration: 116
7) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 57
7) int[ ] sort duration: 33
8) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 115
8) Integer[ ] sort duration: 115
8) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 58
8) int[ ] sort duration: 31
9) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 114
9) Integer[ ] sort duration: 101
9) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 52
9) int[ ] sort duration: 32
10) ArrayList<Integer> sort duration: 113
10) Integer[ ] sort duration: 114
10) Integer[ ] PARALLEL sort duration: 57
10) int[ ] sort duration: 32
```

**EDIT**: Added functionality to sort a `Integer` array.
**EDIT**: Added functionality to sort a `Integer` array using Parallel sort.

Comment: I think, we need to ensure that, all the measurement base on same algorithm/method.  Finally,  intList.sort(null) invoke ComparableTimSort.sort(), Arrays.sort(intArray) invoke  DualPivotQuicksort.sort()

Comment: The `List` can be sorted using parallel stream. There is no parallel stream option for arrays, just a parallel sort.