# Is System.arraycopy() and Array.sort() faster or slower than manual process in Java?

Tags: java, system

I was using these in my code but I think they are may be not as fast as manual coded procedure. I had searched the and found some articles which say that System.arraycopy() is actually faster than copying an array manually. I am not quite sure whether that is correct or not.

Also, the function Array.sort() is the fast compared to what we write in code?

```
// I am merging the arrays here into a new integer array called newarray3 
    int[] newarray3= new int[input1.length + input2.length];
    System.arraycopy(input1, 0, newarray3, 0, input1.length);
    System.arraycopy(input2, 0, newarray3, input1.length, input2.length);

    //sorting the array.
    Arrays.sort(newarray3);
```

input1 and input2 are two arrays which are to be merged and then sorted. I want to know whether coding this way is making my program slower. Or could it be something else. Please help.

Comment: What is manula process?

Comment: Have you tried profiling this code yourself?

Comment: typing mistake I corrected it. I meant "manual" meaning we write the code our-self

Comment: @Bernard yes I tried to the best of my knowledge and I can't think of anything more, which is why I need some guide to help me out.

Comment: `System.arrayCopy()` is way faster and moreover it is implemented in `native` code. Check ***[this](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue124.html)*** page.

Answer (score 2):

System.arraycopy will be faster that what you can do by hand in virtually all circumstances, since it can do "bulk" data moves, vs an element at a time.  The main exception would be relatively small arrays, since the initial processing inside arraycopy, selecting which algorithm to use, is non-trivial.

Re sort, there's no single sort algorithm that is optimal in all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayCopy()` is a native method, so yes it *might* be faster than a pure Java implementation coded by hand. On the other hand, `sort()` is a pure java method, but designed for generic sorting - and the specific algorithm used depends on the data type of the array, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018332/is-java-7-using-tim-sort-for-the-method-arrays-sort) to understand the details.

You could make your own sorting implementation that's faster by improving the comparison between objects and specializing the algorithm for a certain data type, in fact this is the approach recommended in the book [Java Performance Tuning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003773). Anyway, you won't know for sure until a profiler is used for comparison.

Comment: So it could mean that the reason for my code to have a little bit more time complexity is due to the sort()? what sorting algorithm does the sort() use, can you tell ?

Comment: It's possible (profile it first!), but bear in mind that that algorithm is heavily optimized already. Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018332/is-java-7-using-tim-sort-for-the-method-arrays-sort) to understand the algorithm being used