# Insertion Sort LinkedList Java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write an Insertion sort for a LinkedList, I have got a working method but it is incredibly slow. Over an hour to add&sort 50,000 elements.

```
public void insert(Custom c) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(list.get(i).compareTo(c) > 0  )
        {
            list.add(i,c);
            return;
        }
    }
    list.add(c);    
}
```

I know i could use Collections.Sort but for this assignment I am required to write my own LinkedList. I'm not asking for a full solution just some pointers.

Comment: It's probably because you keep calling `list.get(i)` which is an O(n) operation.

Comment: How often does it get to `list.add(e);`? If it's happening often you could try comparing e to the last entry first.

Comment: @MrLore 8 times for 5000 elements

Comment: @user3424480 It may be worth trying it first anyway, that's still 39,992 less calls to `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, insertion sort on a `List` is going to be slow (`O(N^2)`) ... no matter how you do it.  But you appear to have implemented it as `O(N^3)`.

Here is your code ... which will be called N times, to add each list element.

```
public void insert(Entry e) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)       // HERE #1
    {
        if(list.get(i).compareTo(e) > 0  )  // HERE #2
        {
            list.add(i,e);                  // HERE #3
            return;
        }
    }
    list.add(e);                            // HERE #4   
}
```

At "HERE #1" we iterate *up to* M times where M is the current (partial) list length; i.e. `O(M)`.  This is inherent in an insertion  sort.  However, depending on how you implemented the `size()` method, you *could* have turned the iteration into a `O(M^2)` sequence of operations.  (The `LinkedList.size()` method just returns the value of a `size` variable.  No problem here.  But if `size()` counted the elements ... )

At "HERE #2" we have a fetch and a comparison.  The comparison (`compareTo(...)`) is cheap, but the `get(i)` operation on a linked list involves traversing the list from the beginning.  That is an `O(M)` operation.  And since you make the `get(i)` call `O(M)` times per `insert` call, this makes the call `O(M^2)` and the sort `O(N^3)`.

At "HERE #3" the `add(i,e)` repeats the list traversal of the previous `get(i)` call.  But that's not so bad because you only execute that `add(i,e)` call once per `insert` call.  So the overall complexity is not affected.

At "HERE #4" the `add()` operation could be either `O(1)` or `O(M)` depending on how it is implemented.  (For `LinkedList.add()` it is `O(1)` because the list data structure keeps a reference to the last node of the list.)  Either way, overall complexity is not affected.

In short:

- The code at #2 definitely make this an `O(N^3)` sort.
- The code at #1 could also make it `O(N^3)` ... but not with the standard `LinkedList` class.

---

So what to do?

- One approach is to recode the `insert` operation so that it traverses the list using the `next` and `prev` fields, etcetera directly.  There should not be calls to any of the "higher level" list operations: size, get(i), add(e) or add(i, e).

  However, if you are implementing this by extending or wrapping `LinkedList`, this is not an option.  Those fields are private.
- If you are extending or wrapping `LinkedList`, then the solution is to use the `listIterator()` method to give you a `ListIterator`, and use that for efficient traversal.  The `add` operation on a `ListIterator` is `O(1)`.
- If (hypothetically) you were looking for the fastest way to sort a (large) `LinkedList`, then the solution is to use `Collections.sort`.  Under the covers, that method copies the list contents to an array, does an `O(NlogN)` sort on the array, and reconstructs the list from the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/3388491) response, you should use [ListIterator.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29) instead of `List.add` due to the better performance.

Comment: have added an Iterator in now. Performance vastly improved. 50,000 in around 40 seconds now

Answer (score 0):

What about using a faster sorting algorithm?

Here is something known as [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Its way faster then normal sorts for larger data sets. QuickSort has a average case of O(nlogn) while insertion only has a average case of O(n^2). Big difference isn't it?

### Sample implementation

### QuickSort Class

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSort{


    public static void swap(int A[] , int x, int y){

        int temp = A[x];
        A[x] = A[y];
        A[y] = temp;

    }



    public static int[] QSort(int A[],int L, int U){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        if ( L >= U){
            return A;
        }

        if (L < U) {
            /*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              Partion the array around the pivot, which is eventually placed                                                                                                                                                                                                  
              in the correct location "p"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

            */

            int randomInt = L + randomGenerator.nextInt(U-L);
            swap(A,L,randomInt);
            int T = A[L];
            int p = L;

            for(int i= L+1; i<= U; i++){
                if (T > A[i]){
                    p = p+1;
                    swap(A,p,i);

                }


            }



        /* Recursively call the QSort(int u, int l) function, this deals with                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           the upper pointer first then the lower.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        */
            swap(A,L,p);
            QSort(A,p+1,U);
            QSort(A,L, p-1);

        }
        return A;

    }
}
```

### Sample Main

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int[] intArray =  {1,3,2,4,56,0,4,2,4,7,80,120,99,9,10,67,101,123,12,-1,-8};

        System.out.printf("Original Array was:\n%s\n\n",Arrays.toString(intArray));

        System.out.printf("Size of Array is: %d\n\n",intArray.length);

        QuickSort.QSort(intArray, 0, intArray.length - 1);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("The sorted array is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));

    }
}
```

The above example will sort an Int array but you can easily edit it to sort any object(for example Entry in your case). Ill let you figure that out yourself.

Good Luck

Comment: should mention data set has to be sufficiently large however. So you are talking about millions of entries not thousands.

Comment: This could be for an assignment where a insertion-sort is needed.

Comment: Yeah could be, but he doesn't mention he's limited to 50,000 elements... maybe he just gave up cause 50,000 was taking too long

Comment: That is what he is trying to solve, but answering his question by providing an alternative instead of fixing his code doesn't truly answer it. He said in the main post anyway that it was for an assignment.

Comment: I see your point. If he is not limited to insertion sort this would be the way to go for large data sets.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest Insertion sort is required for the assignment but thanks anyway. We were advised to test up to 50,000 elements. I've since used an Iterator instead and insertion is much quicker ~40 seconds for 50,000. Although this is still slower than my Array Implementation. Cheers

Comment: *"Although this is still slower than my Array Implementation."* - Do you mean `Arrays.sort()`?  That's not a fair comparison, 'cos `Arrays.sort()` is not using insertion sort.  It is using an `O(NlogN)` sort ...

Comment: @StephenC ya good question, doesn't Arrays.sort use mergeSort for primitives and QuickSort for objects?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest - it depends on the JVM version.  In Java 7, it is a form of Quicksort for primitives and TimSort for objects - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018332/is-java-7-using-tim-sort-for-the-method-arrays-sort.  But the point is that the algorithms are better than `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @StephenC I'm using my own Insertion sort again in my Arrays implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`list.add(e)` and `list.get(e)` will take o(n) each time they are called. You should avoid to use them when you travel your list.

Instead, if you have to write your own linked list you should keep track of the elements you are traveling. by replacing the operation i++ and get(i) by `elem = elem.next` or `elem = elem.getnext()`, (maybe something else depending on how you implemented your linked list). Then you add an element by doing:

```
elem.next.parent = e;
e.next = elem.next;
elem.next = e;
e.parent = elem;
```

here my example works for a doubly linked list and elem represent the element in the linked list you are currently comparing your object you want to add.