# Java: Racing Arrays.sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I created some improvement to QuickSort and decide to test it against Java `Arrays.sort()`.

The results are fascinating:

On Java 6:

- My Time / System Time = 74 / 83 =    0.891566265060241
- My Time / System Time = 75 / 79 =    0.9493670886075949
- My Time / System Time = 75 / 84 =    0.8928571428571429

On Java 7:

- My Time / System Time = 115 / 70 =   1.6428571428571428
- My Time / System Time = 101 / 76 =   1.3289473684210527
- My Time / System Time = 102 / 61 =   1.6721311475409837

As you can see my algorithm performs better on Java 6, how ever it have a dramatic drop on Java 7 witch I don't understand. May be you can find the reason why?

**Edit: How does my algorithm works:**

- **Step 1:** Take 3 numbers, sort them, use the middle number as pivot
- **Step 2:** Take all the numbers bigger than pivot to the right and all the numbers smaller than pivot to the left, and place pivot in it's final position in the sorted array. This actually implemented in O(N).
- **Step 3:** Recursively repeat step 1 and 2 for left and right sides. When you rich sub array smaller than 12 elements use network sort to sort it.

### My source code

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void sort(int[] source) {
        int buffer[] = new int[source.length];
        concatenate(source, buffer, 0, source.length);
    }

    private static void concatenate(int[] source, int[] buffer, int low, int high) {
        int count = high - low;
        int lowBuffer = low;
        int highBuffer = high;

        if (count < 2) {
            return;
        }

        if (count < 12) {
            networkSort(source, buffer, low, count);
            return;
        }
        int pivotIndex = bestOfThree(source, low);
        int value = source[pivotIndex];

        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
            if (i == pivotIndex) {
                continue;
            }
            if (source[i] < value) {
                buffer[lowBuffer] = source[i];
                source[lowBuffer] = buffer[lowBuffer];
                lowBuffer++;
            }
            else {
                highBuffer--;
                buffer[highBuffer] = source[i];
            }
        }

        buffer[lowBuffer] = source[lowBuffer] = value;
        for (int i = lowBuffer; i < high; i++) {
            source[i] = buffer[i];
        }

        concatenate(source, buffer, lowBuffer + 1, high);
        concatenate(source, buffer, low, lowBuffer);
    }

    private static int bestOfThree(int[] source, int low) {
        int a = low;
        int b = a + 1;
        int c = a + 2;
        int median = -1;

        if (source[a] >= source[b] && source[a] >= source[c]) {
            if (source[b] < source[c]) {
                median = c;
            }
            else {
                median = b;
            }
        }
        else if (source[b] >= source[a] && source[b] >= source[c]) {
            if (source[a] < source[c]) {
                median = c;
            }
            else {
                median = a;
            }
        }
        else if (source[c] >= source[a] && source[c] >= source[b]) {
            if (source[a] < source[b]) {
                median = b;
            }
            else {
                median = a;
            }
        }
        return median;
    }

    private static int[][] networkSort = { 
            { 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2 },
            { 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2 },
            { 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 5, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3 }, 
            { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4 },
            { 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 9, 3, 8, 2, 7, 1, 6, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 9, 0, 3, 5, 8, 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 3, 5, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5 },
            { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 0, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 6, 10, 4, 8, 5, 9, 2, 6, 0, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5, 6, 10, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 4, 7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8 }
        };

    private static int tmp;

    private static void networkSort(int[] source, int[] buffer, int low, int count) {
        int[] networkData = networkSort[count - 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < networkData.length; i += 2) {
            int index1 = low + networkData[i];
            int index2 = low + networkData[i + 1];

            if (source[index1] > source[index2]) {
                tmp = source[index1];
                buffer[index1] = source[index1] = source[index2];
                buffer[index2] = source[index2] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

### Base testing class

```
public abstract class Test {
    protected int[][] buffer;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public int numberOfTests = 100;
    public int maxValue = 1000;
    public int numberOfItems = 100;

    protected void createBuffer() {
        buffer = new int[numberOfTests][];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            int[] list = new int[numberOfItems];
            addRandomNumbers(list);
            buffer[i] = list;
        }
    }

    protected void createBuffer(int...parametes) {
        buffer = new int[1][];
        buffer[0] = parametes;
    }

    protected void addRandomNumbers(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            int value = random.nextInt(maxValue);
            list[i] = value;
        }
    }

    protected int[][] cloneBuffer() {
        int[][] clonedBuffer =  new int[numberOfTests][];
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++){
            int[] clonedList = new int[buffer[i].length];
            int[] list = buffer[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                int element = list[j];
                clonedList[j] = element;
            }
            clonedBuffer[i] = clonedList;
        }
        return clonedBuffer;
    }

    public abstract void test();
}
```

### Performance Test

```
public class PerformanceTest extends Test {

    private final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void test() {
        createBuffer();

        timer.reset();
        testSystem();
        timeResoult("System");

        timer.reset();
        testMy();
        timeResoult("My List");
    }

    public void test(int numberOfTests) {
        long myTotalTime = 0;
        long systemTotalTime = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            createBuffer();

            timer.reset();
            testSystem();
            long systemTime = timeResoult();
            systemTotalTime += systemTime;

            timer.reset();
            testMy();
            long myTime = timeResoult();
            myTotalTime += myTime;

            System.out.println("My Time / System Time = " + myTime + " / " + systemTime + " = \t"
                    + ((double) myTime / systemTime));
        }
        System.out.println("My Time / System Time = " + ((double) myTotalTime / systemTotalTime));

    }

    private long timeResoult() {
        return timeResoult(null);
    }

    private long timeResoult(String source) {
        long time = timer.check();
        if (source != null) {
            System.out.println(source + ">\tTime: " + time);
        }
        return time;
    }

    private void testMy() {
        int[][] buffer = cloneBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            int[] list = buffer[i];
            QuickSort.sort(list);
        }
    }

    private void testSystem() {
        int[][] buffer = cloneBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            int[] list = buffer[i];
            Arrays.sort(list);
        }
    }
}
```

### Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        PerformanceTest testBasics = new PerformanceTest();
        testBasics.numberOfTests = 1000;
        testBasics.numberOfItems = 1000;
        testBasics.maxValue = 1000000;
        testBasics.test(100);
    }
```

Comment: To paraphrase S. Clemens (Mark Twain) - There are now four kinds of lies; lies, damned lies, statistics and [benchmarks](http://www.futuremark.com/support/guides).

Comment: Try increasing the number of items to a million at least. It might be that the this amount of items is not enough for HotSpot to kick in...

Comment: Are you running code compiled for 6 inside a 7 JRE? Or did you recompile at 7?

Comment: What kind of numbers are these? How exactly did you measure them? Did you "warm up" the JIT? If so, how? Are we supposed to extract all that from the code?

Comment: By the way, your rule of choosing the pivot is called "median of three" and well studied.

Answer (score 8):

They changed the sort algorithm of `Arrays.sort` for Java 7. For sorting objects, Arrays.sort now uses algorithm called [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) and dual-pivot quicksort for primitives. More info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018332/is-java-7-using-tim-sort-for-the-method-arrays-sort).

If you really want to use the old one, apparently you can set a system property `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort`.

See Java 7 [compatibility documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html).

Comment: The question is not about what changed in Java implementation but in mine.

Comment: Oops, my bad :). Then I got nothing for you, so much changed in JIT under the covers between Java 6 and 7.