# Collections.sort in java 8 is not working as java 6 while comparator returning 0

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

Recently I updated our application jdk from Java 6  to Java 8 but kept source language level still as Java 6. After change one of our unit tests was failing. 
I noticed that Collections.sort for LinkedList is working different in Java 8 and Java 6. Even when I am Source Level java 8 with JDk 1.8 I am getting same different behavior. 
To recreate problem:
Defining the enum below:

```
public enum Weight {
    A(1), B(0), C(0), D(0), E(2);

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    private int weight;

    Weight(int weight) {

        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return  name() + '(' + weight + ')';
    }
}
```

and a main Class as below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Weight> weightList = new LinkedList<Weight>();
      weightList.add(Weight.A);
      weightList.add(Weight.B);
      weightList.add(Weight.C);
      weightList.add(Weight.D);
      weightList.add(Weight.E);

        Collections.sort(weightList, new Comparator<Weight>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Weight o1, Weight o2) {
                return o1.getWeight() > o2.getWeight()? 1:0;
            }
        });

        System.out.print(weightList);

    }
}
```

The output for running the code under Java 6 is: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java"

[B(0), C(0), D(0), A(1), E(2)]

and output for running code under java 8 is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java"

[A(1), B(0), C(0), D(0), E(2)]

I changed the type from `LinkedList` to `ArrayList` and I am getting the same result but if I am changing the comparator as below then Java 8 is going to sort the array:

```
Collections.sort(weightList, new Comparator<Weight>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Weight o1, Weight o2) {
                return o1.getWeight() > o2.getWeight()? 1:-1;
            }
        });
```

As you see it seems that the java 8 is not sorting the code properly. Is there a bug in Java or am I missing something as usual?

Comment: That comparator is not correctly implemented according to it's contract. You can't just return 0 or -1 if o1.getWeight isn't bigger than o2.getWeight. You need to actually distinguish between both weights beeing equal and o2 beeing bigger. Why not just `return o1.getWeight() - o2.getWeight()`? That seems like the obvious easy solution.

Comment: JavaDoc: ...defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1. Yours returned 0:1 initially, now it is 1:-1. You need to treat equality

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I agree with you but it doesn't explain why it is working in java 6 and not working in java 8.

Comment: Define working. It should not be working when returning only 0 and 1

Comment: @Govan Probably due to implementation details. It does not make sense to reason about "why it is working in java 6 and not working in java 8" because your implementation is not correct.

Comment: *why it is working in java 6 and not working in java 8* - It is *not* working. You treat < and == the same way, so it's actually an undefined behaviour. It works with java6 because you are lucky.

Comment: 0 should be returned if and only if o1.equals(o2) returns true, i.e. when the two objects are equals. Returning 0 allows the jvm to chose the ordering. Probably, the implementation has changed between java8 and java6, hence the resulting ordering is different

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The internal sort algorithm [was changed to Tim Sort for objects and a dual-pivot quicksort for primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018332/1876620) as from JDK 7.

As your comparator was wrong (it was returning 0 for non-equal values), you were very lucky that it didn't break before. Now it breaks as expected.

Answer (score 11):

```
public int compare(Weight o1, Weight o2) {
    return o1.getWeight() > o2.getWeight()? 1:0;
}
```

This definition doesn't meet the contract expected by the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). **`sort`'s behavior is undefined if you pass it an invalid `Comparator`.**

> - The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.
> - The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.
> - Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.

Your function doesn't return `-1` if `o1 < o2`. It returns `0`, incorrectly asserting that the arguments are equal. This also causes it to fail the first bullet: if you flip the arguments, the result needs to change sign.

A correct implementation would be:

```
public int compare(Weight o1, Weight o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.getWeight(), o2.getWeight());
}
```

Comment: Or simply `Comparator.comparing(Weight::getWeight)`.

Comment: I guess the question is also about why 6 and 8 show different results.

Comment: @khachik yes. I am not asking about right code. I just wonder why java 8 is changing the behavior even if I am compiling using the same source  level. Java 6

Comment: @lexicore or better `Comparator.comparingInt(Weight::getWeight);`

Comment: The source level you select during compilation affects only the set of language constructs you can use in the source files. It does not affect the behavior of JDK functions.

Answer (score 5):

As Boris suggested in its comment : your `compare()` method is not correct.

Look at your implementation :

```
 return o1.getWeight() > o2.getWeight()? 1:0;
```

Suppose you have three objects in your list:

- o1 : weigth 3
- o2 : weigth 5
- o3 : weigth 5

Now suppose that `sort()` invokes `compare()` in this way for your list :

`compare(o1, o2)` returns `0`

`compare(o2, o3)` returns `0`

By transitivity, it means that `o1`, `o2` and `o3` have the same order. You don't want that I assume.
If it works on Java 6, it's simply "chance" in the implementation and not a result that you should reliably expect to.

To solve your issue, you have to handle the 3 cases (superior, inferior or equal) :

```
@Override
public int compare(Weight o1, Weight o2) {
    if (o1.getWeight() > o2.getWeight()){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (o1.getWeight() < o2.getWeight()){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which is equivalent finally to write : `return Integer.compare(o1.getWeight(), o2.getWeight())`.

Note that a much better alternative and **[less error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction)** in Java 8 is using the `Comparator.comparingInt()` factory method and used directly the `sort()` method that was introduced in `List`:

```
weightList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Weight::getWeight));
```

Comment: [Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction)

Comment: Using subtraction for an `int` comparator only works, if you know the possible value set beforehand, so that you can guaranty that the difference truly fits into the `int` range and doesn’t overflow. Since you do not know, which constraints the OP’s weight property has, it’s not appropriate here.

Comment: @Holger In some corner cases, it may indeed give unexpected results. I changed.