# Java: Arrays.sort quicksort and mergesort

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why java Arrays use two different sort algorithms for different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707190/why-java-arrays-use-two-different-sort-algorithms-for-different-types)

So I was reading the Arrays [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) on the various sort implementations. What I noticed was that some of the implementations used a tuned quicksort while others used a modified mergesort. Why the discrepancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quicksort is used for arrays of primitive types while mergesort for Object[] arrays.

The main reason why mergesort is used for Objects that mergesort is stable - it does not reorder elements that are equal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

For primitives the stability of the sort is meaningless, as you cannot distinguish two values that are equal. Hence, quicksort is used (except when sorting an array of Objects, for which mergesort is performed). Moreover, quicksort can be done in place, so there is no need to allocate another array.

Comment: In today's world, mergesort has become the dominant sorter, as it can be implemented to use multiple cores

Comment: good point, but JDK doesn't use this for now.

Comment: That said, JDK 7 no longer uses mergesort -- it uses the mythical [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)!

Comment: @LouisWasserman cool, thanks for that piece of info. any reason you refer to it as "mythical"?

Comment: "Mythical" in that it's extremely complicated, and not many people understand it or would implement it themselves, but it's nevertheless scarily smart and fast.