# What's the basic (not immediate) backing data structure used by JAVA TreeSet?

Tags: java, treemap, treeset

So TreeSet uses TreeMap as backing data structures (with dummy vaues corresponding to keys) & TreeMap in turn uses Red-Black tree which is a self balancing BST.

Now what does this Red-Black tree use as a backing data structure? Is it an array or linkedlist?

My understanding is that it's a linkedlist because in TreeSet, operations like .first() return the smallest value & not the root & it has O(1) time complexity.

So basically it's a linkedlist alongwith bunch of pointers for least, greatest, root of linkedlist etc. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Here is another good explanation of your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923407/why-red-black-tree-based-implementation-for-java-treemap?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is neither an array nor a linked list.  It is a *tree* of Java objects, which is distinct from either.

Look at, for example, the difference between the diagram of [a linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and [a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).  They're fundamentally different.

The red-black tree you mention *is* the data structure.  It *does not have* a "backing data structure."

Comment: Thanks !  left and right variable used in entry isnt it sounding like next node and prev node .

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but whatsoever abstract data structure I am using, has to either rely on array or linked list. In that diagram of binary search tree with one Node pointing to another, if I am not mistaken looks like a doubly linked list

Comment: @Little_idiot: "whatsoever abstract data structure I am using, has to either rely on array or linked list" This statement is incorrect.  It might have to rely on either an array or _references/pointers_, or a combination, but those do not imply that a data structure is a linked list.

Comment: Thanks Deleting my answer! But I cant because of its accepted answer!